# How to implement Video Chat in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

Hello i wold like to implement video chat in my iphone application.Please some one tell me how to implement video chat.If i got some code it will be a great help....

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used it before, nor do I know if it has iOS support, but you can check out [SkypeKit](https://developer.skype.com/).